# Why am I getting 60V between the leads of my dryer and the ground?

Tags: electrical, 240v

trouble shooting my dryer, i get 240 across the leads, and 120 from either lead to the neutral... but only 60 from either lead to the ground. is this normal?

Comment: Do you get anything between neutral and ground? Is the ground wire connected at the panel, and is it unbroken from the panel to the receptacle?

Comment: I don't get anything between the neutral and the ground. The ground wire is connected at the receptacle, but i haven't had a chance to check if it is connected at the panel. I will be doing that in about a half hour. I was just curious as to if the 60V reading between the ground and either lead was normoal. Thanks! A

Comment: I believe it is unbroken from the panel to the recptacle... there is certainly no planned interruption to the line between the two ends...

Comment: It is not normal to have 60V to ground.  It should read the same as the neutral.

Comment: looked in the panel, the dryer circuit at the panel is 2 black & 1 white wires w no ground, & at the receptacle its red white & black with ground. At one point we moved our dryer 10 feet further from the panel- we must have put a junction box in the crawl space to make the wire long enough to reach new location. This was years ago. The other thing I notice is that one of the 2 dryer breakers is a bit loose- if you tug on the wire it snaps off of the center rail of the breaker w/out a lot of resistance. it'll pop right back on, and the multimeter does register 240 between leads.

Comment: but, to repeat, either lead and the ground, which only goes to the junction box and not all the way to the panel, registers 60V.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin- just saw your answer. I wonder how the ground going to a terminal in the junction box rather than to the panel would affect that reading?

Comment: If the wire is not attached at the breaker box, then any voltage you see will be due to capacitive coupling with anything around it. If you measured the voltage difference between you and the hot you would get similar voltages. ( Assuming you were only touching the probe lead )

Comment: sounds like i should take the cover off of the receptacle and touch the leads to the wires themselves? Sorry-- i have experience running circuits and installing receptacles etc, but little or no theoretical knowledge... i am just trying to understand if i have a working receptacle before I call the appliance repair guy and spend the bucks... thanks for all your answers.

Comment: @user19810 In addition to Tester101's correct answer of completing your ground circuit, you have two problems with your breakers. First, a breaker should not be that loose. Second, you should not have 2 breakers for your dryer. Both of these problems are critical safety problems. Stop using your dryer immediately and turn off both breakers. Replace those two breakers with one double-pole breaker.

Comment: @longneck Good points

Answer (score 3):

If the ground is not connected in the panel, you could theoretically read anywhere from 0 to 120V line to ground. The ground is floating, and so is not guaranteed to be 0.

Run an unbroken ground conductor from the panel to the receptacle, and your problem will be solved.